# Why am I getting an isEqualToString error in this Cocoa code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I keep getting this error:

[alt text http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/2203/help.tif](http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/2203/help.tif)

What is it? I never even called "isEqualToString".

Here Is my Joke.M

```
@implementation Joke
@synthesize joke;
@synthesize rating;


- (id)init {
[super init];
return self;
 }

- (void)dealloc {
[joke release];
[super dealloc];    
}

+ (id)jokeWithValue:(NSString *)joke {
Joke *j = [[Joke alloc] init];
j.joke = joke;
return [j autorelease];
}

@end
```

And here is joke.h

```
@interface Joke : NSObject {
NSString *joke;
int rating;
}

+ (id)jokeWithValue:(NSString *)joke;

@property (readwrite, copy) NSString *joke;
@property (readwrite) int rating;

@end
```

And here is where joke is being used

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "Joke.h"

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize jokes;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
    self.jokes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"If you have five dollars and Chuck Norris has five dollars, Chuck Norris has more money than you"],
                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"There is no 'ctrl' button on Chuck Norris's computer. Chuck Norris is always in control."],
                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"Apple pays Chuck Norris 99 cents every time he listens to a song."],
                  [Joke jokeWithValue:@"Chuck Norris can sneeze with his eyes open."],
                  nil];
    }
return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
} 


 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { // Saying how many sections wanted (Just like in address, where sorts by first name)
return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [jokes count];
 }


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Team";    
  UITableViewCell *cell = 
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
             initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
   }
cell.text = [jokes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
  }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
 }


 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
 }

 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
 (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
  }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; 
 }

 - (void)dealloc {
 [jokes release];
 [super dealloc];
 }

 @end
```

Thanks

Comment: Some object is being compared like a string. You have to give more information and show some code. Show the code where this is happening.

Comment: Kk I added my code there. Sorry I didnt add before

Comment: Could you post the code where Joke is being used, not just where it's being defined?

Comment: Daniel - add an breakpoint for -[NSException raise] and show us the code where the debugger stops.

Comment: @chaos i added the code where joke is being called

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
cell.text = [jokes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with these lines:

```
Joke *j = (Joke *)[jokes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if( j )
  cell.text = j.joke;
```

Comment: Yeah, this works because cell.text expects a string, not a joke object. Before, cell.text's accessor was comparing the object you gave it (a Joke) to the object it had already (an NSString) and that's why you were seeing that exception. Another way you could have fixed this was to add an implementation of isEqualToString: on your Joke object and forward that request to your joke property.

Answer (score 3):

The stack trace will help you find exactly what is calling `isEqualToString:`.  Unfortunately, it's not giving you any symbols, so you'll have to do a little digging.

In Objective-C methods, there are two hidden parameters which are always passed as the first two arguments: `self`, a pointer to the object to which the message is being sent, and `_cmd`, a pointer to a C string containing the name of the message being sent.  Examining the `_cmd` arguments in the stack frames will help you debug the problem.

The first thing you want to do is set a breakpoint right before the exception is thrown.  Open up the debugger console (Cmd+Shift+R) and add a breakpoint to the function on the top of the stack trace by typing:

```
break 2438463755
```

Now run your app, and the debugger should break right before throwing the exception.  It should also give you a full symbolic backtrace; if not, you'll have to walk the stack yourself.  You can walk the stack and print out the value of the various `_cmd` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You're shadowing a ivar name with the function argument. Try changing your jokeWithValue: method to this:

In joke.h:

```
+ (id)jokeWithValue:(NSString *)aJoke;
```

in joke.m:

```
+ (id)jokeWithValue:(NSString *)aJoke {
     Joke *j = [[Joke alloc] init];
     j.joke = aJoke;
     return [j autorelease];
}
```

Notice that the NSString variable name has changed so it no longer shadows the iVar joke.

**EDIT:**

On seeing how joke is called, it looks as if you're assigning a joke object to cell.text, which I believe is expecting an NSString not a joke.

try setting:

```
cell.text = [[jokes objectAtIndex:index] joke];
```

in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I will be surprised if this turns out to be the problem. He doesn't use the ivar in that method, so it should be safe (if not exactly good practice) to shadow it.

Comment: This wouldn't actually cause his exception as they're both actually NSStrings though. He's probably comparing a Joke object to it's string value joke somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not in the definition of the Joke class, but somewhere it's being used. In most cases with errors like this, it's the result of a memory management error — some object (presumably a string) gets deallocated and another gets allocated in its old memory location. Try running with [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) and see if it turns up a message to a dealloced object.

Comment: This turned out not to be the case here, but I'm leaving it for Google purposes, because it is often the problem in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

your error message isn't being displayed but I'm assuming you've run into a statement which behind the scenes is calling isEqualToString and one of the objects isn't a string