# NSRunningApplication - Terminate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, terminate

How would I use `NSRunningApplication`? I have something opposite of that which is launching an app:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:appName];
```

but I want to close one. I get an error when I debug the code for `NSRunningApp` which is this:

```
NSRunningApplication *selectedApp = appName;
[selectedApp terminate];
```

Is there something wrong? if there is please point it out and how to fix it.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of this other question (same problem: can't send message to instance of wrong class): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930929/isequaltostring-cocoa-error

Comment: @ Peter: only the solution is a duplicate, the question is unique.

Comment: Ok guys can we focus on the question... No one is responding to me... Look at my latest post below at GS's response!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You assign the variable `selectedApp` a `NSString`. Strings don't have the `- (void)terminate` method and therefore it fails. You have to get a `NSRunningApplication` instance pointing to the application.

```
NSWorkspace *sharedWorkspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSString *appPath = [sharedWorkspace fullPathForApplication:appName];
NSString *identifier = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:appPath] bundleIdentifier];
NSArray *selectedApps =
       [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:identifier];
// quit all
[selectedApps makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(terminate)];
```

Comment: ok, sorry if I don't get it... Like my  code that opens an app from just the name, how would something similar like that work? just the terminating. Cuz i don't want to add the path to the application that needs to be closed..

Comment: my new example should be fully functional

Comment: ok i get this erro that NSRunningApplication may not respond to +runningApplicationWithBundleIdentifier

Comment: fixed it, I should have paid more attention to the api.

Comment: Ok, so I don't get any errors but when i type in the name of the app such as safari, in my textbox which is (appNAme) and press enter (to quit) it just quits my program, instead of safari.

Comment: Have you figured out what the problem was?

Answer (score 5):

What does `appName` refer to? If it literally refers to an `NSString` then that will not work.

Since `NSRunningApplication` is a class, you have to create an instance to send it an instance method as you would with any other class.

There are three class methods (see [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) you can use to return an `NSRunningApplication` instance:

```
+ runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:
+ runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:
+ currentApplication
```

Unless you want an `NSRunningApplication` instance based on the current application you are likely to find the first two class methods most useful.

You can then send the `terminate` message to the `NSRunningApplication` instance, which will attempt to quit the application that it has been configured for.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was saying – you need to create an `NSRunningApplication` instance using one of the above methods.

Comment: ok i have this:

NSString *identifier = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:appName] bundleIdentifier];
  NSRunningApplication *selectedApp =
        [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:identifier];
  [selectedApp terminate];

dis still doesn't work,...

Comment: Is `appName` a full path? You have to pass a full path to `bundleWithPath:` for it to return an `NSBundle` instance which you can then call `bundleIdentifier` on. If the path isn't full (or isn't a valid bundle) then it will return `nil`.