# Not able to close a window (QuickTime) with [NSWindow close] or [NSWindow performClose:(id)]

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, quicktime

I am trying to open a video file with Quicktime and then close it. The video file is opening fine with `[NSWorkspase openfile:path withapplication:@"Quick Time Player"]`. But when I am trying to close the Quicktime window nothing happens. Here is the code.

```
NSMutableArray *titles = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] orderedWindows];
int i;
id obj;
NSMutableString *mystring;
for(i=0; i< [titles count]; i++)
    {
    obj = (NSWindow*)[titles objectAtIndex:i];
    mystring = [obj title];
    if([mystring isEqualToString:@"PREVIEW"] == 1 )
    {
    [obj close];
    }
    //NSLog("Title : %@\n",(NSString*)[obj title]);
    }
```

I would be obliged if any one could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won’t work because `orderedWindows` returns only the windows from your application. There is no way to access a `NSWindow` object from another application like QuickTime Player.

To do this you’ll have to use AppleEvents. There are many different ways to send them, but the easiest probably would be [ScriptingBridge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ScriptingAutomation/Reference/ScriptingBridgeFramework/_index.html). Here is a pretty good [tutorial](http://robnapier.net/blog/scripting-bridge-265).

Comment: "orderedWindows" this function is already sending me an array of NSWindows that contains the reference of QuickTime player, because it is originated from my own application, I have NSWindow object for QuickTIme, I just need to close it. Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSRunningApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do this.

An example is given for the same question here:

[NSRunningApplication - Terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481278/nsrunningapplication-terminate)

Answer (score 1):

Hey I found out the solution, it can easily be done through Apple Scripting, below is the script

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    repeat with d in documents
         if name of d is "abc.mp4" then 
             close d
         end if
    end repeat 
end tell
```

its simple and easy. This script would give an error, however it would perform the required task. It will first grab control of the application QuickTIme Player and then iterate to find the window whose title is abc.mp4 and will eventually close it.

Comment: There is a simpler way to do this: `tell application "QuickTime Player" to close (every document whose name is "abc.mp4")`