# Process isn't terminating macOS Application / Killing Running Process

Tags: swift, macos, process, kill, terminate

I am getting all the running process using **getRunningPrcoess()** function. But when I tried to terminate some specific process then the termination function is not working, it doesn't kill the process. Please tell me What's wrong with my code. I am using **killProcess(_ processId: Int)** function and passing the process ID in the parameter to terminate the process. Is there any other way to kill the running process from your application?

```
//MARK:- Variables
var arrApplication: [NSRunningApplication]!

//MARK:- Load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
    tblRunningProcess.delegate = self
    tblRunningProcess.dataSource = self
    getRunningPrcoess()
}

//MARK:- Actions
@IBAction func btnEndTaskAction(_ sender: NSButton) {
    arrApplication[sender.tag].forceTerminate()
    getRunningPrcoess()
}

//MARK:- Functions
func getRunningPrcoess() {
    // Get all running applications
    let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
    arrApplication = workspace.runningApplications
    tblRunningProcess.reloadData()
}

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return arrApplication == nil ? 0 : arrApplication.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    guard let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "RunningProcessTCell"), owner: self) as? RunningProcessTCell else { return nil }
    cell.lblProcessName.stringValue = "Name: \(arrApplication[row].localizedName ?? "N/A")"
    cell.lblProcessId.stringValue = "ID: \(arrApplication[row].bundleIdentifier ?? "N/A")"
    cell.imgIcon.image = arrApplication[row].icon
    cell.btnEndTask.tag = row
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are initializing a new process instead of killing the existing one. `.init()` creates a new process with same identifier and then it's killed. So you need to change your approach here.

Update:
Right solution is to turn off sandbox mode in the Capabilities section of the Project Settings.

Comment: I directly terminated the process as well but it didn't work :( .  like this   arrApplication[sender.tag].forceTerminate()

Comment: yes somehow the reference is wrong. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481299/5769211

Comment: I checked the reference the Identifier is correct. Whenever I kill my own app it works but doesn't work for other running processes.

Comment: I updated my question as well. you can go through it again.

Comment: yeah just a wild guess then maybe OS doesn't allow you because you are in sandbox mode. Try to turn off sandbox mode in the Capabilities section of the Project Settings.

Comment: Thank you @isaim07  It worked. Please post this comment as an answer then I will mark it as a correct answer :)