# How to get the text value of an object?

Tags: objective-c, text, object

How do I get the text value of an object in order to display it in a table?  Other posts say objects are not NSStrings and you need to ask the object for its text.  But how? The error is this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[Names isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf51b60'

for this code in Objective-C:

```
NSString *cellValue = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
return cell;
```

My apologies to all you advanced programers, I'm new at this and could not find the answer in the NSObject documentation either.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of the object? There isn't a canonical "text value" for an object, so multiple methods might fit the bill. A common one is `-stringValue`.

Comment: @outis: No, a common one is `-description`, which is implemented in `NSObject`, and which classes typically override. It returns a string.

Comment: @jbrennan: didn't I just say that?

Comment: @outis yes but not until I had posted my comment (meaning you posted that while I was answering).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-description` method to get the string value of any object, similar to `toString()` in Java.  Many classes also respond to the `-stringValue` method.

However, `-description` is used primarily for debugging purposes.  If the code you posted isn't working that would mean `namesArray` contains something other than `NSString` instances, in which case you will need to find out what kind of objects are in your array; you can't just cast an object to NSString.

Comment: Originally, the code worked when I had string names in the code and they displayed properly in the table.  But I've removed the string names now and am attempting to use CoreData where the user inputs names, they get saved, fetched, and then displayed in the table.  Yes, the namesArray is supposed to contain strings, so maybe the its a CoreData problem that isn't working yet, or I need a stringValue method.

Comment: According the error message you have a class called "Names" that you're treating as a string, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

I feel the answers so far are missing the point of the question.  Your error is saying that the `Names` class doesn't implement `isEqualToString:` method.  This is being called (presumably) because the `UITableViewCell` only changes the `text` of its `textLabel` if the string is different from what's being displayed, and it's performing this comparison using `isEqualToString:`, because `cell.textLabel.text` is an `NSString` property.

However, you're not giving it an `NSString`.  You're giving it a `Names` object, so of course it's not going to work.  Since `Names` is obviously a custom object, you must provide a method to extract a string representation from this object, and you must explicitly invoke that method yourself.

For example, you might implement a method called `-asString` (which would be a horrible name, but this is to illustrate a point), that might look something like this:

```
- (NSString*) asString {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This name is %@", aNameIvar];
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
Name * thisName = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [thisName asString];
return cell;
```

The proper name for this method would be `-stringValue`.  `-stringValue` is used on several Cocoa objects to return a string representation of the data that they hold, such as `NSNumber`, `NSCell` (Mac), etc.

EDIT:

Peter Hosey answered this exact question quite deftly in [this StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930929/isequaltostring-cocoa-error/930959#930959) question.

Comment: I did see Peter Hosey's answer before posting here.  Very similar situation, but I got tripped up when his answer was "ask the object for its text".  I'll try your suggestion for the -stringValue method and see if that works.  Thanks.  Also see my response to Darren; this used to work when I specifically defined the strings, but now am attempting to use CoreData instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to display an object with `NSLog()` and the `"%@"` format, the invoqued method is `-(NSString*) description` if it exists. It is your responsibility to write this method for your own classes.

Comment: Thanks.  Will attempt and see what happens.