# select cell from UITableView and go to the another UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4.3, uistoryboard

i always got an error while at the second tableview. I creating a simple apps using storyboard. the first time my apps run, it will show up a list of data that i created. if user click the row, i want to change into the other page, at the other page there are also have a tableview. I also hardcode the list of data, but i failed to show it.

I always got an error in this part

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SubSiteCellDetail"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [ListDetailSubSite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //this always give me the error
    return cell;
}
```

here is how i create the list of data

```
ListDetailSubSite = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
SubSite *detailSubSite = [[SubSite alloc] init];
detailSubSite.sSubSiteName = [subsite.sSubSiteName stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
[ListDetailSubSite addObject:detailSubSite];


detailSubSite = [[SubSite alloc] init];
detailSubSite.sSubSiteName = [subsite.sSubSiteName stringByAppendingString:@"2"];
[ListDetailSubSite addObject:detailSubSite];
```

here is how i move from UITableView to another UITableView.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSubSiteDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        SubSite *subsetSelected = [ListSubSite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setSubsite:subsetSelected];
    }
}
```

this is my error looks like

```
2012-10-29 15:18:11.127 UniversalStoryBoard[5256:f803] -[SubSite isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9355340
2012-10-29 15:18:11.129 UniversalStoryBoard[5256:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SubSite isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9355340'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13ce022 0x155fcd6 0x13cfcbd 0x1334ed0 0x1334cb2 0x1580ff 0x4fb1 0xb2c54 0xb33ce 0x9ecbd 0xad6f1 0x56d21 0x13cfe42 0x1d86679 0x1d90579 0x1d154f7 0x1d173f6 0x1d16ad0 0x13a299e 0x1339640 0x13054c6 0x1304d84 0x1304c9b 0x12b77d8 0x12b788a 0x18626 0x1fcd 0x1f35)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

here is the pic:

[image: Picture]

class SubSite.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SubSite : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *sSubSiteName;

@end
```

class SubSite.m

```
#import "SubSite.h"

@implementation SubSite
@synthesize sSubSiteName;

@end
```

anyone can help me to solve this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe problem might be because in `cell.textLabel.text = [ListDetailSubSite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` the cell expects a string and not a ListDetailSubSite object..

Similar error was solved in this link:

[Why am I getting an isEqualToString error in this Cocoa code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865527/why-am-i-getting-an-isequaltostring-error-in-this-cocoa-code)

Since you have mentioned that you have created a Subsite classs you can try that method.. basically you need to make sure that the input to `cell.textLabel.text` is an NSString object..

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer.. its really helpful. thanks once again. :)

Answer (score 1):

What is the error you found ?
and have you try this

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat @"%@",[ListDetailSubSite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

I think the problem occur because `cell.textlable.text` accept `NSString` so you need to cast your object

You can do this instead

```
Subset *tmp = [ListDetailSubSite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tmp.sSubSetName];
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. almost solved it, but why the output is like the memory address? how can i get the text from indexpath.row? thanks.

Comment: ya, SubSite is a class. I will add in the SubSite class.

Comment: I improve my answer, hope it help

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. i solved it already. i vote your answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [ListDetailSubSite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

should be replaced by

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[ListDetailSubSite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sSubSiteName]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. but honestly, what kind of different? i mean your answer.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake, now i correct it.hope not misslead you

Comment: hi, its okay.. no worries. I vote your answer because your answer is correct also.. thanks. :)